# iPhone SDK - Converting .mov to .3gp

Tags: objective-c, ffmpeg, 3gp, mov

I need to convert a video in format ".mov" to ".3gp". I searched on Google and I found some people saying to use **ffmpeg**.

I search a lot but I don't found any tutorial to how compile **ffmpeg** for iPhone then convert the video.

Has anyone what have done this or know any tutorial?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` has already been ported to the iOS platform:

[gabriel/ffmpeg-iphone-build @ GitHub](https://github.com/gabriel/ffmpeg-iphone-build)

Alternative: [ffmpeg4iphone - Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/)